# Powershell Sort By Uniqueness of the Hostname

Tags: powershell

Within Powershell, using an array, is it possible to sort in a way that prevents values (e.g. hostnames) not to be sequential? For example, if I have the following below in the Before list. My goals is not to have any servers that shares a similar hostname to be right behind one another when possible. Instead, I would like to have it output to be similar to the After list below.

```
(Before)
Hostnames
DSERVER01
DSERVER02
PSERVER03
PSERVER04
DSERVER05
PSERVER01

(After)
Hostnames
DSERVER01
PSERVER03
DSERVER02
PSERVER03
DSERVER05
PSERVER01
```

Comment: Looks like you want to shuffle the array. Will a random order do, or is the "no similar hostnames next to each other" a hard requirement?

Comment: Randomizing the list does not guarantee your criteria even if it is the easiest and best I see so far.

What is the real reason of your "unsorting" ?

Comment: @vonPryz I prefer it to be a hard requirement, but if not, I'm okay with the solution that gets me the closest.

Comment: @user10722100 I'm looking to do some automation (e.g patching) that requires me not to have multiple servers (with similar function/hostname) rebooted at the same time that provides the same functionality. So my thought was if I can do multiple servers if it was possible to ensure that they were not providing similar functionality.

Comment: @ITPRO85 
If criteria is not having the same role server patched at the same time, why don't you throttle based on defined role ?

Role A - Server 1
Role B - Server 1
....
Then after
Role A - Server 2
Role B - Server 2

And so on....

Comment: It depends on what you find are servers with _"similar function/hostnames"_. Is the first letter decicive or the numer at the end? P.S. In your desired _After_ list you have `PSERVER03` double

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment thread, what you [actually need](https://xyproblem.info/) is a way to group server names so that you don't reboot those on the same time. A [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.3) works nicely here. We'll have server names as keys, and as values we have a custom Powershell object containing server name and boot groups. Then you can select elements based on theri boot groups. Like so,

```
$ht = @{}

$o = new-object psobject -property @{
server = 'DSERVER01'
bootgroup = 'A'
}
$ht.Add($o.server, $o)

$o = new-object psobject -property @{
server = 'DSERVER02'
bootgroup = 'B'
}
$ht.Add($o.server, $o)

$o = new-object psobject -property @{
server = 'PSERVER03'
bootgroup = 'C'
}
$ht.Add($o.server, $o)

$o = new-object psobject -property @{
server = 'PSERVER04'
bootgroup = 'A'
}
$ht.Add($o.server, $o)
```

Now when you want to get a list of servers in boot group A, filter the collection like so,

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | ? {$_.value.bootgroup -eq "a"}

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSERVER04                      @{server=PSERVER04; bootgroup=A}
DSERVER01                      @{server=DSERVER01; bootgroup=A}
```

And if all you need is the server name, pipe it to `select-object`.

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | ? {$_.value.bootgroup -eq "a"} | select name

Name
----
PSERVER04
DSERVER01
```